# New error in Swift that tells me that my delegate is weak

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

```
import Cocoa 

NSApplication.shared.delegate = GenerateRandomNickOnApplicationActivation()
_ = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
```

This gives me the error:

> Instance will be immediately deallocated because property 'delegate' is 'weak'

updated:

this worked.

```
var activation = GenerateRandomNickOnApplicationActivation()
NSApplication.shared.delegate = activation
_ = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
```

Comment: So you add a var to save it by yourself.

Comment: i tried but it wont let me , where should i add the var keyword

Comment: Xcode 4.2? I think you mean Swift 4.2, right?

Comment: just above the line : var activation = GenerateRandomNickOnApplicationActivation(); NSApplication.shared.delegate = activation

Comment: yes i had no problem in 4.1 and nothing else as changed in my code @maddy

Comment: @E.Coms when i do it my app doesnt work anymore

Comment: You may add a class and save it as an instance variable there.

Comment: @E.Coms i tried to do that but then my app wont run right

Answer (score -1):

I can't imagine that the gobal `NSApplication` object is valid *before* the call to `NSApplicationMain()`. One of the main job's of `NSApplicationMain()` (no pun intended) is to create the `NSApplication` object.

A better solution for pre-application startup code would be to use one of the standard application object delegate methods, like `applicationWillFinishLaunching`.

If you need to run code *really* early, define a subclass of `NSApplication`, register its class in your main nib file, and add your startup code to its initializer. You can also include new instance variables, etc., to hold a reference to any value(s).

Comment: The documentation of `NSApplication` says: "In your app's main() function, create the NSApplication instance by calling the sharedApplication class method". The documentation of `sharedApplication` says "Returns the application instance, creating it if it doesn’t exist yet."

Comment: @james bucanek what do you think about my code that i added where it says updated:

Comment: @Willeke: Yes, I agree that you can create the singleton application object by calling the `sharedApplication` factory method ... *but*, one of the tasks of `NSApplicationMain()` is to read the `info.plist` and determine if your application uses a custom subclass of `NSApplication`, and if it does **the singleton `NSApplication` object will be replaced**. So, again, I think this is a fragile use pattern.

Comment: @bibbletriple That should work because you have a strong reference outside the delegate assignment. But for the reasons I've mentioned, I think this is fragile code.

Comment: The singleton `NSApplication` object is not replaced.

Comment: @Willeke: if `NSApplicationMain()` doesn't replace the single app object already created, then you've broken the `Info.plist` file because now the main class property gets ignored. Either way, this just makes fragile codes that depends on side-effects. My suggestion of writing this kind of code in a custom app class' initializer is (a) localized and obvious, (b) doesn't require a `main.swift` hack, and (c) is more robust. IMNSHO

Comment: I didn't break `info.plist`. `NSApplicationMain` does `[MyCustomApplicationSubclass sharedApplication]` and `sharedApplication` returns the existing `NSApplication` object. I agree, `sharedApplication` followed by `NSApplicationMain` is bad design but the gobal `NSApplication` object is valid and it will not be replaced.